# ionic3 - how can i remove the text in the ngFor component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngfor

I use NgFor to generate the component but some text in the button need to remove.
For example,the text in the array is RCDD06.But i want to display it as 06 and the data in the array is unchanged.I have stuck in here about 4hours

Here is the array:

```
[{"name":"RCDD01"},{"name":"RCDD02"},{"name":"RCDD03"},{"name":"RCDD04"},{"name":"RCDD05"},{"name":"RCDD06"}]
```

Here is the code in the html:

```
<button ion-button *ngFor="let item of device"  (click)="getData(item.name)">{{item.name}}</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an custom pipe and change the text by string **replace()** method

html

```
<button ion-button *ngFor="let item of device"  (click)="getData(item.name)">{{item.name | remChar}}</button>
```

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'remChar'
})
export class RemCharPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
    return value.replace(/[a-z]|[A-Z]/g, "");
  }

}
```

import your pipe in declarations of your app.module.ts file

Refer the demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lizcdh?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: You do a big help to me.Your solution work perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear :)